# Is the same anonimous variable calculated twice

Tags: javascript, variables, redundancy

I have an imaginary code in Javascript like this

```
let z = 99999;
if (str.lastIndexOf('_') !== -1)
  z = str.lastIndexOf('_');     
}
```

Will be this snip of code: `str.lastIndexOf('_')` be calculated twice?
Or in this cause: `z = str.lastIndexOf('_') !== -1 ? str.lastIndexOf('_') !== -1 : 99999`;

If this will be calculated twice is it mean that the best way is to put `str.lastIndexOf('_')` into a separate variable and use it in conditions?

I want to know that a deliberate ignoring of execution mode
could be justified by lexical purpose.

Comment: Yes it will. Cache the value

Comment: Yes, it will be calculated twice. So yes it would be better to put the result of that operation in to a variable and re-use it

Answer (score 2):

We can test that by overwriting `lastIndexOf`

```js
const orig = String.prototype.lastIndexOf
String.prototype.lastIndexOf = function(...args) {
  console.log('running lastIndexOf')
  orig.call(this, ...args);
}

const str = '31231231231312_1312312'
let z = 99999;
if (str.lastIndexOf('_') !== -1) {
  z = str.lastIndexOf('_');     
}
```

As you can see, it prints 2 times